# Flutter: shared_preferences on Windows - Cannot create link

Tags: flutter, flutter-sharedpreference

I am trying to install 'shared_preferences':

> flutter pub add shared_preferences

but I got error:

> Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "FileSystemException: Cannot create link, path =
> 'z:\gazer_client\windows\flutter\ephemeral.plugin_symlinks\path_provider_windows' (OS Error: Incorrect function.
> , errno = 1)".
> A crash report has been written to z:\gazer_client\flutter_08.log.

I have set developer mode already:
[developer settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnKU3.png)

- Windows 10
- UAC is ON
- NTFS (of course)

What is wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to delete everything from the `.plugin_symlinks` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
Reason is a project located on a VeraCrypt drive.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/88381